# How to get a list of all nested fields from a JSON file in python3?

Tags: json, python-3.6

I want to read each file like the one shown below:

```
{
    "addr": {
        "street": "29393",
        "apt": "203",
        "addr1": "Oak Avenue",
        "addr2": "Suite 2",
        "city": "Denvrer",
        "state": "CO"
    },
    "disposition": "available",
    "location": {
        "latitude": "203030303",
        "longitude": "929393"
    }
}
```

How can I then get a lit of name-spaced fields in that JSON?   I want a list of unique name-spaced fields, like this:

```
addr.street
addr.apt
addr.addr1
addr.addr2
addr.city
addr.st
disposition
location.latitude
location.longitude
```

How can I achieve that in Python3?

Comment: Please post an attempt at solving the problem yourself, then edit the question with code illustrating how far you got and what the current problem you're facing is. See [mcve] for more information about on-topic questions and visit [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need additional guidance.

Answer (score 1):

For the purposes of what you need here this is sufficient:

```
def get_field_list(somedict, parent=''):
    fieldlist = []

    for k, v in somedict.items():
        if parent:
            fieldlist.append(f"{parent}.{k}")
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            fieldlist += get_field_list(v, parent=k)

    return sorted(set(fieldlist))
```

the result would be:

`['addr.addr1', 'addr.addr2', 'addr.apt', 'addr.city', 'addr.state', 'addr.street', 'location.latitude','location.longitude']`

You can try the whole thing on
https://repl.it/@raa/InsubstantialOutstandingStartups

But you need to consider objects in arrays if that has any chance of happening and also that fields are unique through hierarchical depth which this code does not entertain.